Error Installing Packages with sdkmanager: "Errors during XML parse"
I'm trying to install Android SDK packages using the sdkmanager command, but I keep encountering an error related to XML parsing. Here's the command I'm running and the output I get:
Command:
sdkmanager --verbose "platform-tools"

Output:
Info: Parsing /home/wi2david/development/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/package.xml
Info: Parsing /home/wi2david/development/android-sdk/platform-tools/package.xml
Info: Parsing /home/wi2david/development/android-sdk/tools/package.xml
Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                               
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.             
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...

Despite the process seeming to compute updates, it doesn't install the package. I’ve verified the paths, and the required directories exist.
Environment:

OS: Arch Linux 6.12.4
SDK Manager version: 16.0
Java version: 23

Steps I've Tried:

Checked the permissions of the SDK directories.
Ensured I have the latest version of sdkmanager.
Verified that JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

Despite these checks, the error persists. What could be causing the XML parsing issue, and how can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
